# How to get rid of spaces on the sides when phone is held horizontally?

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari, removing-whitespace

When I open my app in **landscape** orientation on my *IPhone* I am getting this whitespaces.

I was wondering, is there a possible way to **get** **rid** of them or at least make them **different** **color**?

[image]

For example, let's say I have this **template**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Test document</title>
    </head>
    <body
        style="
            background-color: darkslategray;
            color: lightgray;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        "
    >
        <header>Some header content</header>

        <section style="background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit,
            deleniti velit cum sit dolorem dignissimos sunt doloribus quos
            tempore id? A ea totam iusto? Consequuntur at provident maiores
            laboriosam iste unde non blanditiis, nulla ut in hic dolor rem
            beatae quos mollitia quod! Officia exercitationem perferendis unde
        </section>

        <main>
            <h1>Some content here</h1>
            <div>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
                quos possimus fuga voluptatem laudantium aut a tempora. Neque
                magnam rem similique, aliquid blanditiis, atque aspernatur ut
                harum eius nihil voluptates doloremque amet ratione quis fugiat.
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <p>Some footer content</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this case section is not **fully** **stretched** in landscape mode, I want it to be red to the edges:

[image]

P.S. `<meta name="theme-color" content="#000607" />` does not do anything in this case.

Comment: Please show us relevant code. And although you have said vertical, the image is of the device in landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake, of course I was talking about landscape orientation, already fixed it. Speaking about relevant code – there is no specific moments in it, just some basic 100vh, 100vw containers.

Comment: It would still help if you could put up a runnable snippet that definitely shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and please check that it shows the problem on your iPhone. At the moment I cannot reproduce it using 'just' the viewport settings.

Comment: Thanks, done it. Question is now updated.

Comment: When I run your snippet on an iPhone SE IOS 15.4 the red goes right to the edge. What phone and version are you seeing giving the problem, and are you seeing it when you run snippet here?

Comment: I have iPhone 11 Pro IOS 16.1.1, I guess red goes to the edge in your case because your model doesn't have front camera section on the screen. Btw, still can't figure out how to solve this issue.